# Load module in a drush script

Tags: 7, drush

I have a Drush script that I am running from my Drupal environment which loads a particular module that I want to get access to.  Particularly, I want to use one of the functions it has defined in one of it's included files.

I tried just calling the function in my script, but PHP fails with an error citing an undefined function.

I am running the script as follow:

```
drush php-script ~/path/to/script.php
```

And this is my script in its entirety right now:

```
<?php
    $val = biblio_get_contributor(1);

    print_r($val);
?>
```

`biblio_get_contributor($aid)` is most definitely defined in the module.

So to sum up, I need to get this module's functions loaded somehow.  Thoughts?

Comment: I assume this module is enabled?  Does `drush php-eval 'print_r(biblio_get_contributor(1));'` also fail?

Comment: It is enabled.  Also yes, that command fails with the same error: called to undefined function.  The module is most certainly enabled though, as it's live in my dev environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `biblio_get_contributor()` function is located in the includes/biblio.contributes.inc file. The file isn't automatically included by the module unless it needs it, which is probably why you're getting that error.

You can include it into a page build explicitly with the following:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'biblio', 'includes/biblio.contributors');
```

Comment: Right on.  You're the man Clive.